# How do I Iaunch remote debugger in Eclipse in a single action?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jdwp

I am running a server in Maven inside Eclipse on my development machine, which means that I have to wait for the server to start up, then launch the "remote debugger" over JDWP. This is a hassle for what should be a simple debugging operation.

Is there a way to do this with a single command?